# htaccess not working in a hosting

Tags: .htaccess

I'm done a site on XAMPP and I wanted to transfer it on a Hosting.

The problem is the htaccess that does not work in the hosting.

```
    Options -Indexes

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ index.php?url=$1.$3 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^ajax$ _res/ajax.php [QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without *L*:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ index.php?url=$1.$3 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^ajax$ _res/ajax.php [QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

From [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Try test your *.hateaccess* on some [htaccess teste](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)r.